# Substitution of one variable in another

Tags: prolog

Given a list of lists, I'd like to substitute all the `A`s in `B`s, where `A` and `B` are prolog variables.

For example, if the list was `[[1,2,D,C],[A,D],[4,A],[1,2,A]]`
I want the outcome to be `[[1,2,D,C],[B,D],[4,B],[1,2,B]]`

For this I wrote the following, to substitute all the `A`s in `B`s in a single list:

```
/*substitude_single(+OldVar,+NewVar,+OldList,-NewList) */
substitute_single(_,_,[],[]). 
substitute_single(A,B,[A|As],[B|Bs]):-
   substitute_single(A,B,As,Bs).
substitute_single(A,B,[X|As],[X|Bs]):-
   substitute_single(A,B,As,Bs).
```

And now I'm applying this on each element of the main list, which is a list itself:

```
substitute(_,_,[],[]).
substitute(A,B,[P|Ps],[Q|Qs]):-
   substitute_single(A,B,P,Q),
   substitute(A,B,Ps,Qs).
```

The problem occurs when, for example, I test my code on `substitute_single(A,B,[C,A,D,1],X)`, I get many solutions, some are applying values to the variables. For example, I get:

```
A = 1,
C = 1,
D = 1,
X = [B, B, B, B] ;
```

or:

```
A = D,
C = D,
X = [B, B, B, 1]
```

and only after many other solutions, I get:

```
X = [C, B, D, 1]
```

which is the solution I'd like. And yet, there are even more solutions (that I do not wish for) coming after it.

So I tried to cut the program, to prevent it from generating more solutions:

```
substitute_single(A,B,[A|As],[B|Bs]):-
   substitute_single(A,B,As,Bs),
   !.
```

But now, while I do get only a single solution, it is not the one I aimed for!

(For the above example, the solution I get is

```
A = 1,
C = 1,
D = 1,
X = [B, B, B, B].
```

)

I don't know how or where I should change my program so it will only give me the solution I want?

(Note: `A` and `B` might be variables or also constants, for example: `substitute_single(A,3,[C,A,D,1],X)`) should generate `[C,3,D,1]` )

Comment: I'll put a bounty for a pure, monotonic solution as soon as bounties can be offered.

Comment: ... and determinate - for the common cases.

Comment: @repeat , what I meant for `substitute_single/4` is to do the substitution of `A` in `B`, for all the appearances of `A` in a single list. Then I use it for a list of lists, by applying it to each one of the lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with your solution is that you are applying term unification as an equality test, when what you need is a test for strict identical terms for which there is the `==/2` predicate.

For exchanging two terms that may be variables in a single list, assuming a properly closed list and a mode +,?,?,- the following predicate is enough

```
exchgterms([],_,_,[]).
exchgterms([X|Xs],A,B,[C|Ys]) :-
  ( X == A -> C=B ;
    ( X == B -> C=A ; C=X ) ),
  exchgterms(Xs,A,B,Ys).
```

You can start from here to solve your problem, and change it to suit your needs, in particular if your predicate must have a different mode.

**UPDATE**

I changed the name of my predicate to emphasize it also works for exchanging terms that are not variables.

It should be clear that it should replace `substitute_single/4` with the arguments in a different order in the second clause of `substitute/4`, so the solution you seek is

```
substitute(_,_,[],[]).
substitute(A,B,[L|Ls],[R|Rs]) :-
  exchgterms(L,A,B,R),
  substitute(A,B,Ls,Rs).
```

I would advise you change the order of the arguments in `substitute/4` so that the 3rd argument becomes the 1st one. In that form most Prolog systems will know that if this argument is instantiated, as it is the case here, the two clauses are mutually exclusive and this will contribute to a more efficient execution.

Answer (score 1):

`substVarInTerm/4` is what I came up with.

```
:- use_module(library(apply)).

substVarInTerm(A,B,Term0,Term) :-
   term_variables(Term0,Vars0),
   exclude(==(A),Vars0,Vars),
   copy_term(A^Vars^Term0,B^Vars^Term).
```

Note that `substVarInTerm/4` does **not** work if the first argument is something other than a variable.

The *other use cases* you gave work out just *fine*:

```
?- substVarInTerm(A,B,[[1,2,D,C],[A,D],[4,A],[1,2,A]],R).
R = [[1, 2, D, C], [B, D], [4, B], [1, 2, B]].

?- substVarInTerm(A,B,[C,A,D,1],X).
X = [C, B, D, 1].

?- substVarInTerm(A,3,[C,A,D,1],X).
X = [C, 3, D, 1].
```

Comment: If the 1st argument must be a variable then your solution does not follow the note at the end of the question stating that the 1st and the 2nd arguments can be non-variables.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding X \= B to your second clause:

```
substitute_single(A,B,[X|As],[X|Bs]):-
   X \= B,
   substitute_single(A,B,As,Bs).
```

So that it doesn't branch to new solution when X is not B.

Comment: I did, but getting now a `[B,B,B,B]` solution. Anyway, I don't think adding this rule will give me what I wish for. I mean, assume `X=A` (and `A≠B`), so I don't want my solution (after the replacement) to include `A` as well, I want it to have `B` instead..

Comment: The problem seems to be in your testing case. Prolog treats the capitalized inputs as variables. When you test it with `substitute_single(A,B,[C,A,D,1],X).` Prolog sees C, A, and D as variables and tries to give them values, in your case number 1 for each. Try it with atoms beginning with small letters like `substitute_single(a,b,[c,a,d,1],X)` or put the inputs in single brackets like `substitute_single('A','B',['C','A','D',1],X).`

Comment: single brackets -> single quotes

Comment: but I do want them to be variables. I would like to sometime substitute the appearances of a variable in a constant, without actually assigning a value to that variable, and my input is of the form of a list of lists of variables and constants.